# Adjust existing regex to ignore semicolon inside quotes

Tags: regex

I am using a regex to read csv files and split its columns. The input of files changes frequently, and is unpredictable how the content will come (not the format). I already use the following regex to read the csv file and split the columns:

```
;(?=(?:[^\"]*\"*[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)
```

It was working until I faced a input like these:

```
'02'.'018'.'7975';PRODUCT 1;UN;02
'02'.'018'.'7976';PRODUCT 2;UN;02
'02'.'018'.'7977';PRODUCT 3;UN;02
'02'.'018'.'7978';"PRODUCT 4 ; ADDITIONAL INFO";UN;02 // Problem
'02'.'018'.'7979';"PRODUCT 5 ; ADDITIONAL INFO";UN;02 // Problem
```

I would like to understand how I can adjust my regex and adapt it to ignore semicolon inside quotes.

I am using Java with the method split from String class.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Java. Using the method split from String class.

Comment: Perhaps try using [a parser](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html)

Comment: Interesting... I will try this parser. But I am still curious how to make this regex works.

Comment: The only problem with your regex is the `"*`, just need to remove the star.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear in mind that you should probably use a parser for this, but if you must use regex, here's one that should work:

```
;(?=[^"]*(?:(?:"[^"]*){2})*$)
```

#### Explanation

`;` matches the semicolon.

`(?=...)` is a positive lookahead. It checks that the pattern contained in it will match, without actually matching it.

`[^"]*(?:(?:"[^"]*){2})*$` ensures that there are an even number of quotes in the rest of the string.

Comment: It works! Thanks for the answer and I will use a existing CSV parser to read the files. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: Because the `\"*` bit makes that quote optional. It should work if you were to remove the `*` from that.